# Netbeans is not opening

Tags: java, netbeans

I have netbeans 6.8.
I wanted to install jax-rpc plugin and added this link to my plugin finder.
http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

I also did something weird.. i think i did check for updates every startup or everyday.

and now it is showing all these errors and not opening up:

```
Warning - could not install some modules: Bootstrap - The module name   
org.openide.util.lookup was needed and not found. Upgrade - None of the modules  
providing the capability org.openide.modules.ModuleFormat1 could be installed.  
Upgrade  - The module named org.openide.util.lookup was needed and not found. File 
System API - None of the modules providing the capability 
org.openide.modules.ModuleFormat1 could be installed. Module System API - The module   
named org.openide.util.lookup was needed and not found. Startup - None of the modules 
providing the capability org.openide.modules.ModuleFormat1 could be installed. 3 
further modules could not be installed due to the above problems.
```

And two options "Disable Modules and continue." and "exit".

Pressing anyone closes the ide. Also last time when ide was working and installed that plugin it was validating other plugins and i exited during that part.

Comment: What OS? Did you try re-installing NetBeans?

Comment: windows is the os. and i now have netbeans 7.0 in another directory thats working.

Comment: but it would be good if i get my netbeans back...

Comment: I had the same problem today. I went to my ~/.netbeans/7.0/modules folder, sorted the module files according to date and removed today's update. That worked. Netbeans started without issues after that.

Answer (score 2):

You could try deleting the NetBeans cache. On my platform it's in my home directory, `~/.netbeans/7.0/var/cache`.

Comment: 7.0.1 is an update to 7.0. Why not delete your broken 7.0.1, and update your working 7.0? You may wan to backup the working one first.

Comment: I had netbeans 6.8 that stopped working. Now i have installed 7.0 in other directory that is working fine. but cannot open my 6.8 again

Comment: I don't know of any reason they can't co-exist; I see that I have 6.5, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9 and 7.0.

Comment: They can coexist but my 6.8 got bad before 7.0 was installed... in fact i installed 7.0 to work after i could not open 6.8 again

Answer (score 0):

There is a subdirectory "backup" in your .netbeans/7.x/update directory.
It contains (in my case at least) the files shown in the picture:

[image: netbeans backup files]

Just copy them back into the .netbeans/7.x directory, merging and replacing existing files and directories. After doing that, I could start netbeans normally without reinstalling and losing all my addons and preferences.